# Download an image using data URI on Android (Samsung Galaxy S6, default browser)

Tags: android, image, download, base64, data-uri

I'm using Data URIs on my page to display an image. Next to it I provide a download link as well. The image and link look like this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg....//2Q==" alt="description">

<a target="_blank" href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg....//2Q==" download="download.jpg">Download image</a>
```

This works really well on all browsers, including mobile safari, but not on this particular browser. The error message received is this:

"Only http or https Web addresses can be downloaded".

Is there any way around this? I do not have the image available as a file, only as a base64 encoded string.

Comment: Never saw a 'download' attribute in an 'a' tag but shouldnt you change 'download="download.jpg"' to 'download="http://<server>/download.jpg"'?

Comment: The download attibute (HTML5 only, not standard) is used on a tags only to suggest the name of the file to be downloaded. And as I said, I sadly don't have access to the file served from any file server, only a base64 encoded string.